# Current, eminent philosophers addressing political/democratic theory?

Tags: politics, democracy

Are there any well received philosophers still writing today about politics and democracy in 2017 and/or what may be some ways forward for the international community?

Comment: The main problem is that Philosophy as a discipline has much lower profile than it did in the early 20th C, so although there are highly regarded contemporary philosophers of politics, they simply don't have the public visibility that they once did.

Comment: But that does not mean that this may not change in future, even intellectual pursuits have their fashions.